# Tableau calculated field-formula

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a simple formula for calculation in table .

This is the table structure

```
EXPERIENCE  PLATFORM    REVENUE
PC          WEBSITE     100
MOBILE      ANDROID     20
MOBILE      IPAD        10
MOBILE      IPHONE      20
```

My calculation is trying to find the share :

**Calc1**: Share of site= sum of revenue from mobile / sum of revenue (mobile+PC)

**Calc2:** share of platform= sum of revenue from apps/revenue from mobile

Can someone highlight how I can create a formula , I am very new to tableau.

Thanks

Comment: http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields.html

Answer (score 0):

For Calc1, try a calculated field like:
sum(iif([Experience]='MOBILE',[Revenue],0))/sum([Revenue])

Calc2 uses similar logic:
sum(iif([Platform]='ANDROID',[Revenue],0))/sum(iif([Experience]='MOBILE',[Revenue],0))

You should also be able to get what you need using the Tableau built in table calculations, by dragging in what you need and adjusting filters as necessary.